# IOS 10.3.3 not working with SSL and IIS Rewrite Rule

Tags: ios, ssl, ipad, iis, url-rewriting

I have a very specific issue that I'm hoping someone else has come across. It is only occurring on iPads with iOS 10.3.3.
We have a ColdFusion website in IIS on Windows Server 2016 that refuses to load on any iPad with iOS 10.3.3. When you attempt to open the site in Safari it spins for about a minute and then says "Safari cannot open the page because the server stopped responding".

Within IIS, we have a URL rewrite rule that looks similar to the following:

```html
<rule name="All files and directories that don't exist" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*/*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="*CFIDE*" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <serverVariables>
        <set name="NEW_SCRIPT_NAME" value="{R:0}" />
    </serverVariables>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:2}?sub={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
</rule>
```

If I visit the page on Chrome (again using the same iPad), the same issue occurs.

If I visit the page on the iPad using HTTP instead of HTTPS, the rewrite rule works as expected and the page renders.

If I disable the rewrite rule and visit the page on the iPad, the page renders just fine.

If I visit the page on a different iPad with a newer (or older) iOS version (such as 5.1.1), the page renders just fine.

We have not had any issues on any other device or browser. All other devices (Android, Windows, etc) work as expected on all browsers we have tested.

If I look at the IIS and ColdFusion logs, I can see the request come in from the iPad, and it's almost like the device is caught in some redirect loop, as the logs show the same page being requested hundreds of times in a row. We also tried getting a different SSL certificate from a different provider and it made no difference either.

So basically, it appears to be a combination 3 elements: SSL, IIS Rewrite on Windows Server 2016 and iOS 10.3.3. Eliminating or changing any of those 3 elements permits the page to render on our iPads, but unfortunately eliminating or changing any of those 3 elements is not feasible for our situation. iOS 10.3.3 is the latest version available for the iPads that we have.

For context, one of the older iPads we have is on iOS 5.1.1 and it renders the page just fine.

UPDATE: We tried another server that had Windows Server 2012 with IIS 6.2 and it works as expected on the iPad, so Windows Server 2016 is also one of the variables.

ANOTHER UPDATE: Using online browser emulators, it looks like the issue is present on iOS 9.1 through 10.3, whereas iOS <= 8.4 and >= 11.0 do not have the problem. The issue is apparent with Windows Server 2016 and IIS 10.0 where a URL rewrite rule is configured and triggered.

Comment: For a short-term fix, we spun up a Windows 2012 server with IIS 8.5 and the site now works on all devices. Everything other than the IIS version is identical to the Windows 2016 server. It would be really nice to know what it is about the 2016 server that doesn't play nicely with iOS 9-10 and URL rewriting.

Comment: We seem to have run into the same problem. Very frustrating. Please do update if you find a fix.

Comment: By the way, I posted this over at ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/questions/901813/iis-sc-win32-status-64-when-using-url-rewrite-over-https-and-coldfusion

Comment: It's somewhat comforting to know that I'm not the only person out there with this issue. I will definitely update if I come across a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging and digging, I found that this is a known issue related to IIS10 and http/2. Both Adobe and Microsoft got involved and Microsoft should be releasing a fix in April 2018. A short term fix is to disable http/2. Our hosting provider also suggested installing the BonCode connector as a fix.

Note that this does not just affect url rewrite, but also default document settings.

https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4198446

**UPDATE:**
This is fixed as part of KB4093120

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4093120/windows-10-update-kb4093120

Comment: Awesome, thanks for finding this David! We still have our 2016 server set up so I will definitely report back after installing the April 2018 Windows Update rollup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why. The patch didn't fix my problem (IIS 10 on Windows server 2016). Finally, I needed to turn off the http2 in my IIS . I wrote down the experience in the blog

http://dbwizard.blogspot.com/2020/10/iis-connects-to-tomcat-https-bug-in-iis.html